# Updating shortlinks from staging

Tags: plugin-jetpack, shortlink

Many of the shortlinks on pages of our site are links to our staging site. The current live site started life as the staging version, so I imagine that's why, but I don't know how to fix the issue. Does anyone have any tips as to how to achieve this?

**Update** Apologies, this is actually the http://wp.me/... shortlinks created and added to the head of pages by Jetpack. I need to know how to clear/update these, to reflect the change of domain (from staging to production). Hope this is now clearer.

Comment: What do you mean by "shortlinks"? bit.ly or something?

Comment: I have seen `?p=` links refered to as "shortlinks"...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 solutions to your problem:

- You can go to the Jetpack menu in your dashboard and disconnect, then reconnect to WordPress.com. It will force an update of your Jetpack settings.
- You can contact the Jetpack support team here: http://jetpack.me/contact-support/ They can update your Jetpack settings for you.